# When is bundle data cleared by os?

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

Let me directly go to my question, now a days we know from Android 7.0 to high TransactionTooLargeException as a runtime exception occur if size of data exceeds 1mb. i know that we need to reduce transfer high data instead make singleton handle data. i just want to know when the data transfer from one activity to another  or fragment like set argment on viewpager, is been get cleared , or its not cleared even after activty or fragment get destroyed (I mean bundle data).or it keey on stck the bundle value until process get destoyed. please give an idea when data trasfer via bundle get clear, my dount is if bundle data trasfer not get clera even after activit destroy it will exced to 1 mb to make this exception, please help

Comment: If you need to keep that much information in memory or pass it around, you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: no @Henry what i mean i want to know when will bundle data get destroyed or clear?

Comment: am passing 3 int value and6 string value not big data , but my view pager can be  scrolled infinity so what i need to know each time i swipe i have about 100 page in aloop so will that make a crash, i mean transaction too large thats y need to know when bundle data get clear

Comment: whats the diffrent on bundle case?  like if i use FragmentPagerAdapter it will not make update of data also took lot of memory because fragment is not been clearedit taking instance.

Answer (score 0):

When activity pauses it save the state which will include your bundle data. But if you call finish on it the activity will clear all the resources

Incase of fragment as soon as the fragment destroyed the bundle will no longer be saved. Incase of viewpager if you want to store the state you have to manually do it with `statepageadapter` otherwise fragment will not retain its state.

So yes incase of  activity you have to be careful about the bundle size because activities will go to save state during the app use by user.

Comment: ok but on view pager i am using FragmentStatePagerAdapter for fragment on viewpager will it destroy data when i scroll, what i mean is like the fragment get destroy and i com back to it again by scrolling to fragment does it retain the old bundle or new(i mean old bundle data will destry when fragment get destroyed).

Comment: well viewpager adapter will keep the bundlw but it will destroy fragment as soon as it exceed off screen limit. But on returning it will recreate it from the state it stored earlier.

Comment: basically u saying the argument we set on fragment will be get cleared. like we call setargument(), getargument() function inside fragment correct?